# TDD instanceoftype generic interface type of

Tags: .net, generics, tdd, mstest

I'm trying to practice TDD and need to test classes if they implement a generic interface. I'm using MSTest.

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(new Foo(), typeof(IFoo)); // works with concrete interface
```

concept to implement:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(new Foo<AType>(), typeof(IFoo<IType>));
```

What's the best practice for this generic test?

Thank you

Comment: I fail to see the point in testing that class `X` implements interface `IX`, this is compile-time checking and IMO unit tests should be testing run time behaviour.

Comment: Hi Jamiec, I'm using unit tests here to control plumbing. The technical problem I'm trying to solve is I that I need to do reflection on specific types of classes where I'm doing AOP Intercepts on methods with attributes. I want to only look inside specific classes of type repositoryGeneric and want to make sure that all the repositoryies alway implement this interface. I could create another interface, but that would be redundant. I was just looking for ideas from the community. Best, Abe

Comment: The best solution I came up with was to test type for interface as follows

var result1 = typeof(FooRepository<IFoo>).GetInterface("IRepositoryGeneric`2");

then assert.NotNull(result1);
The '2' in the GetInterface() is the number of generic parameters

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest3
    {
        private bool Implements(Type type1, Type type2)
        {
            return type1.GetInterfaces().Any(interfaceType => interfaceType.GUID == type2.GUID);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestClass1ShouldImplementITest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(Implements(typeof(TestClass1<>), typeof(ITest<>)));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestClass2ShouldNotImplementITest()
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(Implements(typeof(TestClass2<>), typeof(ITest<>)));
        }
    }


    public interface ITest<T>
    {
    }

    public class TestClass1<T> : ITest<T>
    {
    }


    public class TestClass2<T>
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's best practice, but this works:

```
Assert.IsTrue(typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface)));
```

Comment: Hi Jocke, thanks for the reply. 

Actually since we're using generics, the
Assert.IsNotNull(typeof(FooRepository<IFoo>).GetInterface("IRepositoryGeneric`2"); works, where the '2 refers to the number of generic parameters.

The correct use for us is to do reflection on the assembly containing the  assemblies with repositories and iterating through them to make sure they all implement on of the expected interfaces. This is a good control for new repositories.

Warmest regards,
  - Abe